# How do we deal with questions that cram in too much?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've seen questions once in a while that cram in too much, rather than asking a specific question orientated to a text.

How do we suggest that they try to edit it down and cut out 'buzzwords', and make it specific?

Good questions, I feel ought to be simple, without displaying too much cleverness.

Answer (score 2):

Why not break them apart?

1. Reframe the question so that it focuses on a specific and answerable concern.
2. Create new questions yourself (factored out from the original) and assign them to community. Or better yet try to educate the contributor about how to do this, and suggest ways to decompose the query.

To keep it cohesive you can always bring some loose coupling back in the form of links between the questions.

Comment: In passing: it strikes me that most of the issues with these busy questions are basically XY problems. In general a lot of the things new users tend to pose at the community quite point-blank (without context) *would be constructive questions for us* if they were posed more gradually, iteratively; in other words, starting from the specific problems people are encountering, and building towards the big ideas.

Comment: Excellent point @JosephWeissman, you have described my situation perfectly: anxious to tackle Kant's bigger epistemic questions while still acquiring the many tools for the job. I shall attempt to narrow in .. !